# Python: linear algebra package with domain checks

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

Does it exists a (possibly efficient) linear algebra package that uses some form of domain check before performing linear operations?

`numpy` performs already some kind of domain check before linear operations: if dimensions don't match, it raises a `ValueError`. I would like to identify my domains more accurately (e.g. by having a tag that specifies the basis of the space) and obtain the same behavior if the domains don't match.

Suppose I have a two 3-d vecor spaces

- Vector space `A` represents fruits: dimension 1 = bananas, 2 = apples, 3 = pear. A vector of `A` is a recipe
- Vector space `B` represents clothes: dimension 1 = shoes, 2 = trousers, 3 = shirts. A vector of `B` is a wardrobe.

The following is what I would like to have (and can't do in `numpy`)

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3], domain='fruits')
b = np.array([3,2,1], domain='clothes')
a + b # I want it to raise a ValueError: can't sum clothes and fruits
```

Comment: what do you mean by the basis of a domain? The eigenvectors?

Comment: Thanks for the interest, let me know if my edit clarifies what I mean.

Comment: Since these expressions are mathematically permissible, it is unlikely that a linear package can offer you what you want. Whether the calculations make sense or not is probably for the user to check by implementing his/her own criteria. In other words, for matrices A and B, the multiplication A*B is allowed when cols(A) = rows(B). Whether this multiplication makes sense or not (for whatever reason) is for the user to judge.

Comment: Of course I am willing to provide extra information about the domains at the moment of matrix construction.

Comment: Using `numpy` code, show us what it means for `vector v of a vector space A`.  In other words, define a sample `A` and derive a `v`.  `vector space` and `domain` aren't `numpy` concepts.  WIth out details like that this question will be soon closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can roll your own vector spaces by [subclassing numpy arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.subclassing.html#slightly-more-realistic-example-attribute-added-to-existing-array). I managed to come up with a simple subclass that is essentially a `numpy.ndarray` plus a name. By restricting addition and subtraction to arrays of the same type name, we can essentially do what you're trying to achieve. This assumes that you really want a vector space: in this case we only need to define addition between vector elements, but not multiplication (although that is also easy to implement in the same way).

Here's my class:

```
import numpy as np

class named_ndarray(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, name, inparray):
        obj = np.asarray(inparray).view(cls)
        obj._name = name
        return obj

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        if obj is None: return
        self._name = getattr(obj, '_name', None)

    def __add__(self,other):
        if np.isscalar(other) or (type(other)==type(self) and other._name==self._name):
            return named_ndarray(self._name,np.asarray(self) + np.asarray(other))
        else:
            raise TypeError('Named type "{}" can only be added to the same type! (Other is "{}")'.format(self._name,other._name))

    def __radd__(self,other):
        return __add__(self,other)

    def __sub__(self,other):
        if np.isscalar(other) or (type(other)==type(self) and other._name==self._name):
            return named_ndarray(self._name,np.asarray(self) - np.asarray(other))
        else:
            raise TypeError('Only same type can be subtracted from named type "{}"! (Other is "{}")'.format(self._name,other._name))

    def __rsub__(self,other):
        if np.isscalar(other) or (type(other)==type(self) and other._name==self._name):
            return named_ndarray(self._name,np.asarray(self) - np.asarray(other))
        else:
            raise TypeError('Named type "{}" can only be subtracted from the same type! (Other is "{}")'.format(self._name,other._name))
```

The first two methods are the `ndarray` equivalents of `__init__()`. This class can be used by specifying a name and initializing from an existing array or list:

```
fruitvec1 = named_ndarray('fruits',[1,3,5])
fruitvec2 = named_ndarray('fruits',[2,4,6])
clothesvec = named_ndarray('clothes',[1,1,1])
```

By overriding the `__add__`, `__radd__`, `__sub__` and `__rsub__` methods we can ensure that only named arrays of the same type and scalars (ints, floats, etc.) can be added. By leaving multiplication/division alone, these will work as expected for scalars (and two objects like this shouldn't be multiplied by each other). If you want to go beyond a linear space, you should define `__mul__`, `__rmul__`, `__truediv__`, `__rtruediv__` similarly (the latter assume Python 3 or `from __future__ import division`).

Here's how these objects behave:

```
>>> fruitvec1*3
named_ndarray([ 3,  9, 15])
>>> 3/fruitvec1
named_ndarray([ 3. ,  1. ,  0.6])
>>> fruitvec1 - 2*fruitvec2
named_ndarray([-3, -5, -7])
>>> fruitvec1 + clothesvec/4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "foo.py", line 17, in __add__
    raise TypeError('Named type "{}" can only be added to the same type! (Other is "{}")'.format(self._name,other._name))
TypeError: Named type "fruits" can only be added to the same type! (Other is "clothes")
```

Comment: This is the behavior I was looking for! I deduce that there is no such a library already implemented.

Comment: @dPol not that I know of, but then again I don't work with any formal algebraic problems. I suspect that something like this *might* be implemented in some symbolic math library, but even than that would be slow. If you just want to make sure that your separate types can't mix, this is a fairly simple hack to do it.